# discord.py: I have 2 message processes for my discord bot. Only one out of the 2 will work, how can i make these both work?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a discord bot which detects [SCP Classifications](http://www.scp-wiki.net/) and returns a link to the SCP on the SCP wiki.

However, I also have commands, but they do not work as the code for detecting SCP classifications is in the same file. If i have the classification code first, the classification doesn't work. If the commands come first, they don't work.

I tried moving the blocks of code around each other, but only one or the other will work. I'm stuck on trying to combine them smoothly. I also tried moving the commands to a background task, but its finicky.

**Since you would need to see the entire file, here is my github link: https://github.com/avrwhy/Marvin-Discord-Bot/blob/master/Marvin-Main.py**

I'd like both the commands and the classification detection to work at the same time, but i can't put my finger on what's wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually work with discord.py rewrite, so I'm not too sure but I think you can't have two `on_message` functions.

Comment: @Vulpex this could be it. However, if you see at the end of the classification code, theres the async on_message. I tried moving that into the commands section and they both didn't work. So it's finicky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple `on_message` events with the `@client.event` decorator. The solution would be to merge everything into one `on_message`.

**Note:** You *are* allowed to have multiple `on_message` events per cog, but you aren't using the discord.py cog functionality here.

Comment: I will try to combine all of it.